# Unable to install anchor-cli using Cargo

Tags: rust

I am following the course of Solana Blockchain developer with JavaScript and Rust. I am installing all the necessary frameworks and files. While installing anchor-cli using Cargo. I am getting the following error.

```
error: failed to run custom build command for `hidapi v1.3.4`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `/tmp/cargo-installBgqF19/release/build/hidapi-8cca28feeebdc649/build-script-build` (exit status: 101)
  --- stdout
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=LIBUDEV_NO_PKG_CONFIG
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_PKG_CONFIG
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=LIBUDEV_STATIC
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=LIBUDEV_DYNAMIC
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_ALL_STATIC
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_ALL_DYNAMIC
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_PATH_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_PATH_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_PKG_CONFIG_PATH
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_PATH
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR

  --- stderr
  thread 'main' panicked at 'Unable to find libudev: `"pkg-config" "--libs" "--cflags" "libudev"` did not exit successfully: exit status: 1
  error: could not find system library 'libudev' required by the 'hidapi' crate

  --- stderr
  Package libudev was not found in the pkg-config search path.
  Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libudev.pc'
  to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
  No package 'libudev' found
  ', /root/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/hidapi-1.3.4/build.rs:57:54
  note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
error: failed to compile `anchor-cli v0.24.2 (https://github.com/project-serum/anchor?tag=v0.24.2#0b4c7b0c)`, intermediate artifacts can be found at `/tmp/cargo-installBgqF19`

Caused by:
  build failed
```

Answer (score 0):

In https://project-serum.github.io/anchor/getting-started/installation.html#install-yarn, say On Linux systems you may need to install additional dependencies if cargo install fails. On Ubuntu, ... sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get install -y pkg-config build-essential libudev-dev